# ¿Debo actualizar las tablas?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, sqlite

Tengo una base datos simple me piden añadir dos tablas más, al crear el diseño veo que unas tablas ya existentes de la base de datos tengo que añadir foreign key para poder unirlas a las nuevas tablas, mi pregunta es, primero creo las tablas y después actualizo las otras añadiendo las fk a ellas?

Comment: si, justamente así.

Comment: Debo seguir algún orden??

Comment: el que describiste.